# Lazy loading working in non-transactional class/method in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

I am working in `Spring-Hibernate` application. Flow is as usual: `Controller --> Service --> DAO`.

I have annotated Service layer class with `@Transactional`, thereby marking every method transactional in that class.In service class, I made a `DAO` call to get some domain object and then converting it into `DTO/VO` object which will be passed to controller.For converting domain object to `DTO`, I have written another custom static class(class having only static methods) like `ObjectMapper` which will do this conversion.

Now, domain object has some child object(`One to Many`) which is lazily loaded. So, when in `ObjectMapper`, i access that child getter method, an extra database call is issued, which is working fine.
What I don't understand is that since `ObjectMapper` is not `transactional`, I was expecting some exception to be thrown like `Session is closed` while making database call to fetch child object from database.I am using `getCurrentSession` of `Session Factory` in `DAO`.

Can someone please explain me this behavior?

Comment: if the relation is one-to-one or Many-to-One it's by default eagerly fetch

Comment: It's One to many relation..have updated the same in post

Comment: Are you sure you don't access to this collection before giving it your ObjectMapper ? Does you ObjectMapper call inside your service ?

Comment: Yes, I call ObjectMapper inside service, but getter of child object is invoked inside ObjectMapper

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you either call your ObjectMapper from the transactional Service method (you should) or if not, maybe you are enabled  "hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" which keeps the hibernate session open

Comment: Yes, I am calling ObjectMapper from transactional Service method but still should it work?

Comment: yes, as long as you call the mapper from the transactional method then the session is open for sure

Comment: But somewhere I read that @Transactional doesn't work for method call inside method since Transactional is run by Spring AOP.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the call to the static class/method, which transforms your objects, is made in the transactional method of the DAO, the session is still open and will be used for the database calls.

Comment: But ObjectCaller is neither Spring bean or @transactional..so how come it is working??

Comment: There you go every thing that is called inside a transactional method is transactional. The transaction start before the call of your method and stop after the method return.

Comment: But somewhere I read that @Transactional doesn't work for method call inside method since Transactional is run by Spring AOP.

Comment: Yes, if there is no open transaction and you want that method call to start a new one, then it will not work. But this is different from your case.